# Difference between two models in R programming language

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

I have a research about the effect of the predictors (A, B, C) on X (Note that the predictor A is a main predictor). I analyzed my data using mixed effect linear regression. The dependent variable is X. Random intercept for participant was also included in the models.I run the models in R programming software.

The code is :

```
X.lmer = lmer(X ~ (1|participant) + A * B * C)
```

1. When I run the first code I got results of three-way interaction, in this case, can I speak about the results of the two-way interactions in the results or because with the three-way interaction I cannot relate to the two-way interaction anymore?

The second code is :

```
X.lmer2 = lmer(X ~ (1|participant) + A * B + A * C)
```

2. Do I use this model when the result of the first model is not significant?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a question where a good answer is going to be longer than the question. (Part 1: explain the principle of marginality, probably also clarifying whether the predictors are continuous or categorical; part 2. Discuss the issues of prediction vs inference and the problems of model selection based on hypothesis testing ...)

Comment: The second model omits both the three-way interaction and the two-way interaction `B * C`.  But if the first model is not significant, it's difficult for any model obtained by removing terms to be significant. Before running any of these models you should get clear in you mind what it is you wish to test in your data.